# Graphics32: Pan with mouse-drag, zoom to mouse cursor with mouse wheel

Tags: delphi

I need to implement a pan as I click and drag the mouse, and zoom/unzoom towards/away from the mouse cursor that uses the mouse wheel. (In Delphi 2010, with the image anchored to left,right,top,bottom the form.)

I've just installed Graphics32 and seen how its built-in scroll bars and .Scale allow some of this. It's tantalizingly easy to at least get that far.

Questions:

Is Graphics32 a good tool for this kind of thing? Are there other (perhaps more simple?) tools that I might look into?

Does anyone have any pointers or sample code on how to implement the above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Graphics32 provides a component named TImgView32 which can zoom by setting the Scale property. The appropriate way to do so is by using the OnMouseWheelUp and -Down events. Set TabStop to True for triggering these events and set Centered to False. But scaling in this manner does not comply with your wish to center the zooming operation at the mouse cursor. So repositioning and resizing around that point is a nicer solution. Further, as I understand, the image is always aligned in the top-left corner of the component, so panning must also be accomplished by repositioning the component.

```
uses
  Windows, Classes, Controls, Forms, GR32_Image, GR32_Layers, Jpeg;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ImgView: TImgView32;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ImgViewMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure ImgViewMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer; Layer: TCustomLayer);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    FDragging: Boolean;
    FFrom: TPoint;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ImgView.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('D:\Pictures\Mona_Lisa.jpg');
  ImgView.TabStop := True;
  ImgView.ScrollBars.Visibility := svHidden;
  ImgView.ScaleMode := smResize;
end;

procedure TForm1.ImgViewMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
const
  ZoomFactor: array[Boolean] of Single = (0.9, 1.1);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  MousePos := ImgView.ScreenToClient(MousePos);
  with ImgView, MousePos do
    if PtInRect(ClientRect, MousePos) then
    begin
      R := BoundsRect;
      R.Left := Left + X - Round(ZoomFactor[WheelDelta > 0] * X);
      R.Top := Top + Y - Round(ZoomFactor[WheelDelta > 0] * Y);
      R.Right := R.Left + Round(ZoomFactor[WheelDelta > 0] * Width);
      R.Bottom := R.Top + Round(ZoomFactor[WheelDelta > 0] * Height);
      BoundsRect := R;
      Handled := True;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ImgViewMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer; Layer: TCustomLayer);
begin
  FDragging := True;
  ImgView.Enabled := False; { Temporarily, to get MouseMove to the parent }
  FFrom := Point(X, Y);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDragging then
    ImgView.SetBounds(X - FFrom.X, Y - FFrom.Y, ImgView.Width, ImgView.Height);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := False;
  ImgView.Enabled := True;
  ImgView.SetFocus;
end;
```

**Edit:** Alternative with TImage instead of TImgView32:

```
uses
  Windows, Classes, Controls, Forms, Jpeg, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    procedure FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure ImageDblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ImageMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    FDragging: Boolean;
    FFrom: TPoint;
    FOrgImgBounds: TRect;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoubleBuffered := True;
  Image.Picture.LoadFromFile('D:\Pictures\Mona_Lisa.jpg');
  Image.Stretch := True;
  Image.Height := Round(Image.Width * Image.Picture.Height / Image.Picture.Width);
  FOrgImgBounds := Image.BoundsRect;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
const
  ZoomFactor: array[Boolean] of Single = (0.9, 1.1);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  MousePos := Image.ScreenToClient(MousePos);
  with Image, MousePos do
    if PtInRect(ClientRect, MousePos) and ((WheelDelta > 0) and
      (Height < Self.ClientHeight) and (Width < Self.ClientWidth)) or
      ((WheelDelta < 0) and (Height > 20) and (Width > 20)) then
    begin
      R := BoundsRect;
      R.Left := Left + X - Round(ZoomFactor[WheelDelta > 0] * X);
      R.Top := Top + Y - Round(ZoomFactor[WheelDelta > 0] * Y);
      R.Right := R.Left + Round(ZoomFactor[WheelDelta > 0] * Width);
      R.Bottom := R.Top + Round(ZoomFactor[WheelDelta > 0] * Height);
      BoundsRect := R;
      Handled := True;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
  if FDragging then
    Image.SetBounds(X - FFrom.X, Y - FFrom.Y, Image.Width, Image.Height);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Image.Enabled := True;
  FDragging := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.ImageDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image.BoundsRect := FOrgImgBounds;
end;

procedure TForm1.ImageMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if not (ssDouble in Shift) then
  begin
    FDragging := True;
    Image.Enabled := False;
    FFrom := Point(X, Y);
    MouseCapture := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Wow!  That's exactly what I was looking for, NGLN.  Welcome to SO!  I Normally, I'd figure out code like this, but AFAIK, this will be my only use of G32, so I REALLY appreciate your helpful post.  Final question: how would I reset the view to the way it was when the program started?

Comment: Store the initial BoundsRect in a separate private field, e.g. FOrgImgBounds.

Comment: Remark: Apart from the nice drawing techniques of Graphics32, this code doesn't use any of the advanced functionality of TImgView32. Basically, you could also use the standard lightweighted TImage. Then you have to rewrite the code for zooming, for TImage is a TGraphicControl and has no OnMouseWheel events.

Comment: NGLN: Thanks again! The code's working great. Two minor problems:  zooming way in or out results in a "Can't allocate the DIB handle" exception. I've examined the contents of R in ImgViewMouseWheel, hoping that it would be evident to me how to detect they are out of range, but it's not evident to me. (Nor did a try-except around BoundsRect := R; catch the error.) #2: Setting ImgView.BoundsRect := FOrgImgBounds; when double clicking unzooms in a weird manner, eventually losing the image completely...

Comment: #1: I can't reproduce that error, but I dó have added the detection. #2: That must has something to do with the DoubleClick conflicting with the MouseDown. Also solution provided for. See edit in answer.