# How to zoom images loaded in TImage control in Delphi XE2 Trial?

Tags: delphi, zooming, delphi-xe2, timage

I have developed a small utility to load different types of image files in `TImage` control in Delphi XE2. Now I would like to implement and test zooming functionality, with built-in controls only (i.e. not using any 3rd party component).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049047/graphics32-pan-with-mouse-drag-zoom-to-mouse-cursor-with-mouse-wheel/6050477#6050477) which zooms in and out a TImage by using the mouse wheel.

Note: It repositions the image component.